# DateDifference on VSTO C#

Tags: c#, macros, vsto

```
differencedate = mspApp.DateDifference(task.BaselineStart, tsv.StartDate, mspApp.ActiveProject.Calendar);
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(differencedate.ToString());
```

no result is shown, the messagebox did not display. I have tried different solutions like converting the parameters to DateTime. Weird part is, the IDE shows the syntax and parameters needed to run this function.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, substract date?

Comment: I am converting an old macro to VSTO, the original code in macro is: 

If tsk.BaselineStart >= tsv.StartDate And tsk.BaselineStart <= tsv.StartDate + 7 And tsk.BaselineFinish <= tsv.StartDate + 7 Then
                    differencedate = Application.DateDifference(tsk.BaselineStart, tsk.BaselineFinish, ActiveProject.Calendar) / 60

and more, it just cant fit here. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [DateDifference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864591.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method returns an integer which is the duration in minutes between the dates, for an **automatically scheduled task**.

To get a difference between two dates for a **manually scheduled task**, which uses an effective calendar that can include non-working time, use the [EffectiveDateDifference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865694.aspx) property.